# Remove html tags from json response in reactsjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, tags

I am confused about how I can remove HTML tags from a JSON response in reactjs. This is the JSON response:

```
{
    "price": "26,800.98",
    "diff": "<!--daily_changing-->+13.44 (+0.05%)&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"icon-arrow-dark-circle-right-up zoom-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>",
    "diff_xs": "<!--daily_changing-->+13.44 (+0.05%)&nbsp;<span class=\"icon-arrow-dark-circle-right-up zoom-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>",
    "price_diff": "<!--daily_changing--><div class=\"current_sub_pos\"><span class=\"current_sub_price\">26,800.98&nbsp;</span>+13.44 (+0.05%)&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"icon-arrow-dark-circle-right-up zoom-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
}
```

I want to get diff value +13.44 within react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
const jsonData = {
"price": "26,800.98",
"diff": "<!--daily_changing-->+13.44 (+0.05%)&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"icon-arrow-dark-circle-right-up zoom-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>",
"diff_xs": "<!--daily_changing-->+13.44 (+0.05%)&nbsp;<span class=\"icon-arrow-dark-circle-right-up zoom-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>",
"price_diff": "<!--daily_changing--><div class=\"current_sub_pos\"><span class=\"current_sub_price\">26,800.98&nbsp;</span>+13.44 (+0.05%)&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"icon-arrow-dark-circle-right-up zoom-icon\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>"
}
const deleteHtml = jsonData.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
console.log(deleteHtml);
```

see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `your_string.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');` will remove the html